# How should i properly encode a string containing HTML (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, xss, esapi

My code is having XSS Scripting vulnerability and i want to prevent that. I am using a Jquery Encoder to prevent XSS Scripting .
Following is the JS Code.

```
function test(response)
{

    $('#test').html( $.encoder.encodeForHTML(response));
}
```

The Contents of the response is this

```
response="<html><body><table><tr><td>DATA1</td><td>DATA2</td></tr></table></body></html>"
```

so when i do $.encoder.encodeForHTML(), i expected the output will be a Table  (Before using the encoder i was properly getting a table format), but now, the response string itself is getting printed inside the div element.

Can Someone please help me with this.. I need to encode the response (which contains a HTML Code) as such, so that i get the Output as a proper table format.

Am i going wrong somewhere or am i using a wrong function to encode? Suggestions Welcome.

Comment: Your response is already encoded. Why would you want it encoded twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `var encodedData = encodeURI(htmlDataToEncode);` before you pass it as a response.

Comment: So i need to encode the response before passing it... and decode it in the function here... and then set it inside the div tag using .innerHTML() ?

Comment: correct. You want to encode it with encodeURI() so that all special characters are encoded before the response is sent from the front end, with your 'responseHandler' function, put it back into whatever format you need it. Then, dump the formatted returned/handled response into your div.